# mysql query returns empty results intermittently

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that sometimes returns an **empty set** on the master but NEVER on the read replica and there is data that is there that match on both databases. It is random and am wondering if there is a mysql setting or something with query cache. Running mysql 5.6.40-log on rds.

<strike>I have tried doing `optimizer_switch="index_merge_intersection=off"` but it didn't work.</strike>

**UPDATE optimizer_switch="index_merge_intersection=off seems to have worked, but I cleared the query cache after making this change and the problem seems to have resolved itself).
One really odd issue that happened is the query worked via mysql command line 100% of the time; but the web application didn't work until I cleared the query cache (even though it connects as the same user).**

Once I do optimize table `phppos_items` it fixes it for a little bit (3 minutes) and then it goes back to being erratic (mostly empty sets). These are all innodb tables.

settings:

https://gist.github.com/blasto333/82b18ef979438b93e4c39624bbf489d7

Seems to return empty set more often during busy time of day. Server is rds m4.large with 500 databases with 100 tables each

Query:

```
SELECT SUM( phppos_sales_items.damaged_qty ) AS damaged_qty, 
        SUM( phppos_sales_items.subtotal ) AS subtotal, 
        SUM( phppos_sales_items.total ) AS total, 
        SUM( phppos_sales_items.tax ) AS tax, 
        SUM( phppos_sales_items.profit ) AS profit
FROM  `phppos_sales` 
    JOIN  `phppos_sales_items` ON  `phppos_sales_items`.`sale_id` =  `phppos_sales`.`sale_id` 
    JOIN  `phppos_items` ON  `phppos_sales_items`.`item_id` =  `phppos_items`.`item_id` 
WHERE  `phppos_sales`.`deleted` =0
AND  `sale_time` BETWEEN  '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND  '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
AND  `phppos_sales`.`location_id` IN ( 1 ) 
AND  `phppos_sales`.`store_account_payment` =0
AND  `suspended` <2
AND  `phppos_items`.`deleted` =0
AND  `phppos_items`.`supplier_id` = '485'
GROUP BY  `phppos_sales_items`.`sale_id`
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type        | possible_keys                                                                                 | key                         | key_len | ref                                                   | rows | Extra                                                                                                   |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_items       | index_merge | PRIMARY,phppos_items_ibfk_1,deleted,deleted_system_item                                       | phppos_items_ibfk_1,deleted | 5,4     | NULL                                                  |   44 | Using intersect(phppos_items_ibfk_1,deleted); Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_sales_items | ref         | PRIMARY,item_id,phppos_sales_items_ibfk_3,phppos_sales_items_ibfk_4,phppos_sales_items_ibfk_5 | item_id                     | 4       | phppoint_customer.phppos_items.item_id       |   16 | NULL                                                                                                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_sales       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY,deleted,location_id,sales_search,phppos_sales_ibfk_10                                 | PRIMARY                     | 4       | phppoint_customer.phppos_sales_items.sale_id |    1 | Using where                                                                                             |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you receive an error code back or anything? Are you sure where WHERE conditions are always true? Could this be an issue with isolation/serializability?

Comment: No error code back, just empty result set. Only seems to happen often during busy time of day. Where conditions are always true

Comment: mysql bug reference is https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79675